# Trigger Point of Moving average crossover

Tags: pandas, dataframe, triggers, moving-average

I am trying to define the trigger point when wt1(Moving average 1) crosses over wt2(moving average 2) and add it to the column ['side'].

So basically add 1 to side at the moment wt1 crosses above wt2.

This is the current code I am using but doesn't seem to be working.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.wt1.iloc[i] > df.wt2.iloc[i] and df.wt1.iloc[i-1] < df.wt2.iloc[i-1]:
        df.side.iloc[1]
```

If I do the following:

```
long_signals = (df.wt1 > df.wt2)

df.loc[long_signals, 'side'] = 1
```

it return the value of 1 the entire time wt1 is above wt2, which is not what i am trying to do.

Expected outcome is when wt1 crosses above wt2 side should be labeled as 1.

Help would be appreciated!

[image: Sample_data]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and your expected output please?

Comment: Updated @sophocles

Comment: btw when somebody suggests you post some data they do not mean a picture of it; pls see [asking good Pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Use `shift` in your condition:

```
long_signals =    (df.wt1 > df.wt2) & (df.wt1.shift() <= df.wt2.shift())
df.loc[long_signals, 'side'] = 1
df
```

if you do not like NaNs in `'side'`, use df.fillna(0) at the end

Your first piece of code also works with the following small modification

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.wt1.iloc[i] > df.wt2.iloc[i] and df.wt1.iloc[i-1] <= df.wt2.iloc[i-1]:
        df.loc[i,'side'] = 1
```